# saving entity with referenced dependent entities using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using Hibernate as persistency layer and have complex object model. Without exposing the real data model I want to explain the problem using the following simple example.

```
class Person {
    private Integer id; //PK
    private String name;
    private Account account;
    // other data, setters, getters
}


class Account {
    private Integer id; //PK
    // other data, setters, getters
}
```

The DB mapping is defined using HBM as following:

```
 <class name="Person" table="PERSON">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <version name="version" type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" length="50" column="NAME"/>
    <many-to-one name="account" column="ACCOUNT_ID"
                class="com.mycompany.model.Account"/>

</class>
```

I have to save new populated instance of `Person` linked to existing `Account`. The call is originated by web client, so at my layer I get instance of Person referenced to instance of `Account` that holds its ID only.

If I try to call `saveOrUpdate(person)` the following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: 
com.mycompany.model.Account
```

To avoid this I have to find the persisted object of `Account` by ID and then call `person.setAccount(persistedAccount)`. In this case everything works fine.

But in real life I deal with dozens of entities referenced to each other. I do not want to write special code for each reference.

I wonder whether there is some kind of generic solution for this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To persist one entity, you just need to have the references to its direct dependencies. The fact that these other entities reference other entities doesn't matter.

The best way to do it is to get a proxy to the referenced entity, without even hitting the database, using `session.load(Account.class, accountId)`.

What you're doing is the right thing to do: get a reference to the persistent account, and set this reference into the newly created account.

Comment: Thank you, @JB Nizet. This is actually what I expected... I will post here description of my generic solution and will be glad to know your opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate allows you to use just reference classes with ID, you don't need to do session.load().

The only important thing is that if your reference object has VERSION, than the version must be set.
In your case you have to specify version of Account object.

Comment: Is this described in the Hibernate documentation, or any other documentation available?

Comment: Love you man! I add the version to my class and I couldn't save it anymore by just setting the ID, wasted lots of time with that problem

Comment: I would expect JPA to do this. Is it possible tell JPA "please persist that reference and use the latest version" without manually adjusting the object graph? There are usecases where I really don't care about the version but I want this reference.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cascade="all"` on the * -to- * mapping

Comment: @Bozho, I added `cascade`. Actually I just forgot to mention that I already played with it. Now when I try to save person with transient account that holds legal ID I get exception like the following: `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.mycompany.model.Person entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cascade="save-update"` in `many-to-one` element? Hibernate defaults to `cascade="none"`...

Comment: I tried, @Nacho. It does not work correctly. It throws other exception (see my comment to Bozho's answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for helping. I have already implemented my own generic solution but wanted to know whether other solutions exist.

I want to share with you the idea. I call the referenced entities that do not contain anything except ID (or other field that can be used to identify the entity uniquely) `placeholder`.

So, I created annotation @Placeholder and put it on all referenced fields. In our example it is on account field of Person class. 
We already have class named `GenericDao` that wraps Hibernate API and have method `save()`. I added yet another method `saveWithPlacehodlers()` that does the following. It discovers the class of given object by reflection, finds all fields marked with annotation `@Placeholder`, finds the objects in DB and calls appropriate setter in main entity to replace the referenced placeholder by persistent entity.

Annotation `@Placeholder` allows to define field that will be used to identify the entity. The default is `id`.

What do you think, guys about this solution?

Comment: Those "automatic" solutions have to be handled with care. If I understand your descriptions right, you are resolving the dependencies in the Save method which handles one object at a time. If you are saving a lot of objects in one unit of work, you are loading all dependent objects one by one, which is very inefficient. Typically, the database operations are done by a repository or a service class, both of which should have a good idea of their job. They can load a lot of entities in one go (e.g. using an in clause) or also verify whether dependent entities are persisted already.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution to problem - using the default constructor of the entity you want a reference for and set id and version (if it is versioned). We have following dao method:

```
public <S extends T> S materialize(EId<S> entityId, Class<S> entityClass) {
        Constructor<S> c = entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        c.setAccessible(true);

        S instance = c.newInstance();
        Fields.set(instance, "id", entityId.getId());
        Fields.set(instance, "version", entityId.getVersion());
        return instance; // Try catch omitted for brevity.
}
```

We can use such an approach because we don't use lazy loading but instead have 'views' of entities which are used on the GUI. That allows us to get away from all the joins Hibernate uses to fill all eager relations. The views always have id and version of the entity. Hence, we can fill the reference by creating an object which would appear to Hibernate as not transient.

I tried both this approach and the one with session.load(). They both worked fine. I see some advantage in my approach as Hibernate won't leak with its proxies elsewhere in the code. If not properly used, I'll just get the NPE instead of the 'no session bound to thread' exception.