# Error saving entity referencing a @Version entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a serious problem persisting an object with a relation with another entity. When I try to save my Account entity (see below) setting the account owner (User entity) with a User object with just the "id" property set it throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.teless.model.domain.Account.owner -> com.teless.model.domain.User
```

> Code

```
//Works
accountRepository.save(
        Account.builder()
                .name("conta 1")
                .owner(userRepository.findOne(1L))
                .build());

//Throws Exception
accountRepository.save(
        Account.builder()
                .name("conta 1")
                .owner(User.builder().id(1L).build())
                .build());
```

> User Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sq")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "user_sq")
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Account> accounts;
    private @Version Long version;

}
```

> Account Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "account_sq")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "account_sq")
    private Long id;  
    private String name; 
    private @ManyToOne User owner;
    private @Version Long version;

}
```

---

## EDIT

I found out the problem. There is no need to load the entity, you can do what I was doing (creating a new entity and set the id).

I found the source of the issue after reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422525/5219299, since I have a @Version on my User entity, I also need to set the version before saving it.

For now I changed the version to a primitive value (long) and I'm able to save the account entity with no problem. But I would like a little explanation here, and to know what is the best practice to tackle this problem.

Comment: Because you are associating a new instance of User (despite the fact you set the ID) so you need to apply the necessary cascade on the @ManyToOne

Comment: @AlanHay but the account entity here is the child class

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @AlanHay, could you give a little more information? I don't want to modify the user when saving/creating a Account instance. Thanks

Comment: Use your code that works because that is the correct way to do it. You can replace findOne with a call to getOne which will set the reference to the existing User without requiring a DB lookup. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-

Comment: Thanks @AlanHay, it works the way you said as well. But I don't get it why I'm getting a transient error if the User object has the primary key set. When I wasn't using Spring Data this same approach worked

Comment: Even setting the id field, your `User` instance is not linked with the row representing the user on the database, and some way Hibernate knows that and the exception is thrown. I guess Hibernate stores (somewhere, someway) the relation between your entity and the rows on DB, and your `User` is not there.